# Problem calling webservice from Silverlight in VisualStudio 2010

Tags: silverlight, webservice-client, nusoap

I'm trying to consume a WS written in nusoap from Silverlight. When I add WSDL service reference, in VS21010, I see listed all WS functions.
I instanciate object in my code behind:

```
serviceclient cl=new serviceclient();
```

But when I digit cl. I cannot see ws methods in IntelliSense. Why?
The same thing, made in a windows form application runs fine.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you inspect the Reference.cs file that VS2010 generated for your Service Reference? The file I mentioned resides in the directory [projectfolder]/ServicesReferences/[YourServiceReferenceName]

Comment: I'll go to check it; what can i modify in this file?

Comment: You shouldn't modify it because its autogenerated but you could at least check if it contains anything meaningful.

Comment: it does not contain expected methods i'm waiting but i don't see errors at all. If i make a non-silverlight project instead i see all web service method, so it seems like a Silverlight issue...

Comment: Which version of SL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the register method. There is parameter called Use. Make sure you pass it as 'literal' and style as 'rpc' . Make sure your ComplexType if you have, does not use 'Soap-Enc:arrayType'.